# Automatic user input while the script is running

Tags: python, azure, automation, azure-cli

I am writing a python script for Azure Image deletion.
When I make the Azure CLi call, it asks me are you sure want to delete it ? y/n. But since i'm deleting hundreds of images, i want to automate this user input part. Can someone show me how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for whatever command you're running?

Comment: got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will totally depend on the command that you're trying to execute, and hence looking at the Azure CLI [command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest) would help. Please check if there is any option similar to `--force` that would execute the operation without prompting.